# query on date returning incorrect results

Tags: mysql

Why would this include those records also which are created on 2016-10-31? Shouldn't this be showing results after 10/31 and before 11/5?

### Query

```
select distinct id, createdate 
from ticket_history 
where createdate > '2016-10-31' 
  and createdate < '2016-11-5'
```

### Output

```
'14725', '2016-10-31 08:00:28'
'14726', '2016-10-31 08:32:29'
'14727', '2016-10-31 09:58:09'
'14728', '2016-10-31 10:27:38'
'14729', '2016-10-31 10:52:38'
'14731', '2016-10-31 14:01:42'
'14734', '2016-11-02 11:38:30'
'14735', '2016-11-02 14:02:57'
'14736', '2016-11-02 14:34:30'
'14742', '2016-11-03 14:08:44'
'14745', '2016-11-03 23:32:55'
'14746', '2016-11-04 08:34:18'
'14747', '2016-11-04 09:43:42'
'14748', '2016-11-04 12:32:56'
'14749', '2016-11-04 14:24:44'
'14750', '2016-11-04 16:53:44'
```

Comment: the query looks ok, what is the problem?

Comment: Because using just `'2016-10-31'` means `'2016-10-31 00:00:00'` so try `where createdate > '2016-10-31 23:59:59'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly dont say that., the query already say `< '2016-11-05'` if want include `11-05 xx:xx:xx` change to `< '2016-11-06'`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yea I spotted that and quickly remove the evidence of my stupidity ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select distinct id, createdate 
from ticket_history 
where date(createdate) > '2016-10-31' 
  and date( createdate) < '2016-11-5'
```

Comment: even when this work, this **cant** make use of index, so will have slow performance.